# Extend existing MVC site to pass new data into ViewData for every action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

We have a white-labelled platform built on Asp.Net MVC2.  At present the site has 6 controllers, as well as all the core views etc that can enable it to work straight out of the box.  So far we've built 5 sites from it and it's all been great.

Now, however, I have a requirement that means I need to be able to pass a new piece of data (in the ViewData dictionary will be fine) to **all views** from any action.  This data is seeded from query string and then from a cookie.

One of the primary reasons for this is to be able to add an extra image to the site's master page depending on this data's value.  I could of course be really dirty and place the deserialization code in the master page; but I'd rather find a way to ensure that it gets added to the ViewData for every request ***that doesn't involve controller inheritance and action method overriding***(!).

Any ideas greatly greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom action filter attribute and apply this attribute to a base controller or all actions that need to have this information injected:

```
public class AdditionalViewDataInjectorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["foo"] = "bar";
    }
}
```

And then decorate your base controller with this attribute:

```
[AdditionalViewDataInjector]
public class BaseController: Controller { }
```

In ASP.NET MVC 3 there's a notion of [global action filters](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) so that you don't even need to have a base controller or decorate all your actions with this filter. There's a [workaround allowing you to achieve the same in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FluentFilters.aspx). Now all your views get this additional property in the view data.

This being said, the previous is an ugly workaround and not something I would recommend (ViewData is ugly). You may take a look at [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helpers. Here's how this might look:

```
public class MySpecialController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Here you have access to the request, cookies, session, routes, ...
        var someModel = GetSomeModel();
        return View(someModel);
    }
}
```

Then have some strongly typed partial which will contain the required HTML (`~/Views/MySpecial/Index.ascx`) and finally include this in your master page:

```
<%= Html.Action("index", "myspecial") %>
```

Comment: Genius - the latter solution of using child actions works absolutely perfectly and fits in nicely with how the site already stacks up. I have the data as an action method parameter which uses a custom model binder (that interacts with the cookies and querystring), which then fires a partial view for the content, simply passing the bound object in as the model.  The master then just uses a single line Html.RenderAction() and now it works on all pages.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnResultExecuting` in your base controller and add required data to the `ViewData` property..

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext ctx) {
    ViewData["title"] = "Hello world!";
    base.OnResultExecuting(ctx);
}
```